# How do I print an increasing value with iteration in LaTeX?

Tags: calculations, calc

For example, I want to print all values x + 1 with n repetition

In Python it would be:

```python
def arithmetic_add_1_(n,x):
  for k in range(n):
    print(x)
    x = x+1
  print(x)
```

with n -> repetitions
and  x -> start number

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to clarify your problem and make yourself familiar on how to ask a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/asking). Asking a well formulated question with enough details will increase your changes to get a good answer.

Comment: Is this question python or TeX related?

Comment: My question is related to TeX, I know how to do it in Python or other languages but I would like to know how to do it in LaTex

Comment: You can do this kind of thing in a variety of ways using `expl3`. Have a look at the manual which you can get by running `texdoc interface3`. If no one else gets there before me, I'll give an answer.

Comment: As a side comment, I would rather discourage you from doing programming of this kind in LaTeX as long as you don't have a high level of understanging TeX. It is definitely *possible*, but (La)TeX is a rather unforgiving as a programming language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it in `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% #1: start number
% #2: number of repetitions
\cs_new_protected:Nn \debush_arithmetic_incr:nn
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {#1}
    \int_do_while:nNnn { \l_tmpa_int } < { #1 + #2 }
      {
        \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int
        \c_space_tl
        \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \ArithmeticIncr } { m m }
  {
    \debush_arithmetic_incr:nn {#1} {#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ArithmeticIncr{10}{8}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Since your function performs assignments, it should be defined with `\cs_new_protected:Nn`

Answer (score 11):

You can do that with very basic means.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ArithmeticAdd}[2]{\edef\myindex{#1}%
\loop
\myindex\par% replace \par by whatever allows you to separate the integers
\edef\myindex{\the\numexpr\myindex+1}%
\ifnum\myindex<\numexpr#1+#2+1\relax
\repeat}
\begin{document}
\ArithmeticAdd{12}{7}
\end{document}
```

One could also work with counters (but there could be problems with the name space if some other routine uses this counter), and there is also `tikzmath` which supports a syntax that is closer to your code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\tikzmath{function arithmeticadd(\x,\y) {int \k;
     for \k in {\x,...,\the\numexpr\x+\y}
     {print{\k};}; 
  };
  arithmeticadd(12,7);
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Simple and elegant without `expl3`.... I like your style :)

Answer (score 9):

An answer not using any pre-existing loop macro but rather simply recursing on the main print function

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\iter#1#2{#1\ifnum#1<#2\relax, \afterfi\iter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}\fi}
\def\afterfi#1\fi{\fi#1}
\begin{document}

\iter{6}{15}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Since you're familiar with Python, you may find the following, LuaLaTeX-based solution interesting.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\ArithmeticAdd[2]{%
   \directlua{ for j = #2 , #1+#2-1 do tex.print ( j ) end }}
\begin{document}
\ArithmeticAdd{8}{10}
\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, this solution is fully expandable. Of course, whatever is in arguments 1 and 2 has to expand to an integer in order for this approach to generate meaningful results.

Answer (score 6):

You can utilize the `pgffor` package. See more in [pgfmanual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), *Section 88
Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement*.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
This is a list of numbers:
\foreach \i in {6,7,...,30}{\i, } 
this is the alphabetic list
\foreach \i in {a,...,z}{\i, } 
and this is the alphabetic list in capital
\foreach \i in {A,C,...,Z}{\i, } 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

A fully expandable `expl3` version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand {\arithmeticadd} { mm }
 {
  \debush_arithmetic_add:nn {#1} {#2}
 }
% #1: start number
% #2: number of repetitions
\cs_new:Nn \debush_arithmetic_add:nn
 {
  \int_eval:n { #1 }
  \int_step_function:nnN { #1+1 } { #1+#2 } \__debush_arithmetic_print:n
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__debush_arithmetic_print:n { ~#1 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\arithmeticadd{10}{7}

\end{document}
```

This only adds a space between the numbers, because the first item is typeset by itself and the loop starts from the following one.

[image]

Comment: Nice. I have never noticed these functions in the manual before. Maybe I only read up to §20.6 Integer Expression Loops… Am I right in guessing that this is more efficient than my answer (as well as being expandable)?

Comment: @DavidPurton I tested with `l3benchmark` and the present code is indeed more efficient than yours.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you re looking for ist `\foreach`.

Do you mean something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \n in {10}{
    \foreach \x in {3,...,\n}
    {   
        \ifnum \x < \n
        \draw (\x,0) node {\x};
        \fi
        \draw (\n,0) node {\n};
    }
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's kind of this idea but I would like to do this with a custom start value like in my python example so how could I do this ?

Answer (score 3):

Another TeX solution, using the original syntax OP specified

```
\def\enuminterval#1#2{%
    #2 \ifnum#1=0 \else
    \expandafter\enuminterval
        \expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\expandafter}\expandafter{\the\numexpr#2+1\expandafter}%
    \fi
}

\enuminterval{10}{8}
```

Output: `8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18`